# Is there a quick way/ shortcut for expanding contents in brackets for VS code (Not collapsing/expanding methods)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, shortcut, expand

So my teacher typed this code all in one line:

```
Alert.alert("Invalid Number!", "Number has to be a number between 1 and 99.", [{text: "OK", style: "destructive", onPress: resetInputHandler}]);
```

then pressed something to auto format it to this:

```
Alert.alert(\
"Invalid Number!",\
"Number has to be a number between 1 and 99.",\
[{text: "OK", style: "destructive", onPress: resetInputHandler}]\
);
```

where each content moved to its own line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably use [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) and its [VS Code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) which formats your code
whenever you hit "Save" or activate the "Format Code" command.

Answer (score 0):

He probably used the `Ctrl+K Ctrl+F` hotkey.

The right click menu has Format options:

[image]